# Cannot create SSL connection after move from CXF 2.5.3 to 2.6.0

Tags: java, web-services, apache, ssl, cxf

When I moved to **CXF 2.6.0**, I'm allways getting this error:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

On CXF 2.5.2 and 2.5.3 worked everythings fine and also works.

What could be different in this case between 2.5.3 and 2.6.0 version.
I use Java API and not Spring.

Thank for some help!

Comment: Check this link (http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/CXF-HTTP-Conduit-settings-not-loaded-Pls-Help-td4766809.html) maybe it will help

Comment: Thank you for comment! But I'm using Java API and not Spring.